# KLM flight from Brussels, pick up ticket from Air France/KLM terminal at Brussel-Zuid/Midi station

Tags: trains, brussels, klm

I have a KLM flight the day after tomorrow, the first leg is a train journey from Brussels to Schiphol. I don't know the Brussel-Zuid/Bruxelles-Midi train station well. I have been trying to find out where exactly the Air+Rail terminal is at the station but no luck!

Does anyone know if it is close to the Thalys (Amsterdam train) area, the Eurostar entrance, or elsewhere in the train station?

Comment: It's in the southern passageway, close to platforms 1-6. It's "behind" the Eurostar area if you come from the main passageway. Hard to find a map where it's visible... Ah here's one: https://expatlove.wordpress.com/tag/bruxelles-midi/ (number 75, bottom right)

Answer (score 1):

As written in a comment by @jcaron:

> The ticket pick-up is in the southern passageway, close to platforms 1-6. It's 'behind' the Eurostar area if you come from the main passageway. Hard to find a map where it's visible.

Quote slightly doctored to make it easier to understand.
The map is no longer available, site is now private.

I found two maps of the station, [one in many versions.](https://maps-brussels.com/brussels-zuid-station-map)
[And this one.](http://ontheworldmap.com/belgium/city/brussels/brussels-midi-train-station-map.jpg)
Neither has the information about the pick-up point. Although the location should be included in the map, there is not label to identify it.